# R script to find the file of biggest size in a folder and then copy that file to other location

Tags: r, rename, filesize

I want to find the most recent jpeg or jpg file that is bigger than 500 KB. I know that below command will return all files that match extensions that I need.

But how could I find the most recent file that is higher than 500 kb? Once I find that file, how to copy it to some other location and rename it to "circle.jpg"? I want a command that will overwrite if "circle.jpg" exists at the new location.

```
filenames <- Sys.glob(c("*.jpg","*.jpeg","*.JPG","*.JPEG"))
```

Comment: `file.info`, `file.copy`. There is a robust help system in R. But, this task seems more well suited to bash or powershell.

Comment: maybe something like `system("cp $(find *.jpg -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +500k -print0 | xargs -0 ls -t | head -1) ./circle.jpg")` ?

Comment: @rawr please put this in answers section

Comment: @rawr how could i search for all 4 types of file ("*.jpg","*.jpeg","*.JPG","*.JPEG") instead of just *.jpg? I tried your command, it gave error -`FIND: Parameter format not correct
Warning message:
running command 'find *.jpg -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +500k -print0 | xargs -0 ls -t | head -1' had status 2 `:(

Answer (score 0):

```
#find the most recent jpeg file >500kb and copy it to a location
setwd("C:/watch")#set folder location
filenames <- Sys.glob(c("*.jpg","*.jpeg","*.JPG","*.JPEG"))
file_list=file.info(filenames)
file_list$Size_in_KB=file_list$size/1024
file_list=file_list[file_list$Size_in_KB>300,]
file_list=file_list[order(file_list$mtime),]
file_list=tail(file_list,1)
file.copy(row.names(file_list)[1],"C:/Documents/",overwrite=TRUE)#destination folder to copy. The command will overwrite if a file exists
```